# battery balancing

Tags: batteries, balancing

I am using a balancing circuit for a 3S (3 series 11.1V) li pol battery. The chip I am using is the S8204B. I am unable to understand the datasheet properly. I have basically 3 components in my system -
1) Li pol charger circuitry, 2) 3S li pol battery and 3) Load.

The datasheet states EB+ and EB-. What do they stand for.
How do I connect the 3 modules.
I am attaching 2 images which I feel. But, I can find flaws with both. Can anyone suggest the optimal usage of this chip pls. The images are attached -

[image: attach1]

[image: attach2]

datasheet - http://datasheet.sii-ic.com/en/battery_protection/S8204B_E.pdf

Comment: Why are you adding an extra "Li Po battery" block to that circuit? The batteries are already in the circuit - did you overlook them?

Comment: So are u saying that the VC1,Vc2,...etc are all that denotes the battery. Then what is EB+ and EB-.

Comment: No, VC1 etc don't denote the battery - the battery symbols denote the battery. I would imagine "EB±" refer to the "External Battery" connections - i.e., the external connections to this battery pack system - where you connect the load or the charger.  Think laptop battery, where this chip is inside the battery pack.

Comment: This chip is part of the battery pack, so EB-,EB+ mean "Battery -, Battery +". It cannot be used to charge balance a separate 3-cell pack with only 2 connections. If you have a separate pack that brings out the internal cell connections, you connect those to VC1 to VC4 via the resistors shown. Charger and Load connect to EB-,EB+.

Comment: hello Brian,
I am using those hobby king batteries with 2 really thick wires (Vcc and Gnd) and 4 small really thin wires. So what you are saying is I connect the thick wires to EB+ and EB-,right. While the smaller wires are connected to the VC1 to 4.
In that case how do I connect the load and the charger circuitry.

Comment: Not necessarily, I don't know what's in those batteries. You might be right for EB+ which connects directly to VDD, VCC1. But the negative thick wire might connect to VSS, in which case connecting it to  EB- would short out the protection FETs. Or there might be circuitry in the hobby king batteries I don't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to connect your tree cells is in the attached image here[image: battery protection], the IC needs to protect your tree cells from overcurrent and overcharge and short circuit and cut the connection between the charger and the battery in case of battery failure of charge or discharge phases.

Comment: Hello Codo. I aam using the hobby king batteries which have 4 thin and 2 very thick wires. The 4 thin are for balancing I assume. How is ur diagram mapped into it pls.

Comment: The balancing is not mapped in my diagram because your IC don't have balancing function, the balancing function is performed in some IC but not in S8204B. For the balancing you need to use S-8209B http://datasheet.sii-ic.com/en/battery_protection/S8209B_E.pdf with balancing function like is shown in the figure 17 from the datasheet.